# Redirected to login in Umbraco only when using Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, umbraco, response.redirect

I have a macro that detects whether the visitor is coming from Facebook and if that visitor is an administrator on that facebook-page.

When I detect an administrator I run the code below to log the visitor in as a pre-defined administrator (an Umbraco backend User) and redirect to the live editing mode. **This works perfectly in Chrome, but does not work in Internet Explorer.** In internet explorer the visitor is redirected on top level (outside the iframe) to the Umbraco Login page, not logged in. Any idea why?

```
var id = umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.getUserId("exampleadminuser"); // LoginName of an administrator
var u = umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.GetUser(id);
umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.doLogin(u);

// Check if the user should be redirected to live editing
if (u.DefaultToLiveEditing)
{

    int startNode = u.StartNodeId;

    // If the startnode is -1 (access to all content), we'll redirect to the top root node
    if (startNode == -1)
    {
        if (umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.GetRootDocuments().Length > 0)
            {
            startNode = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.GetRootDocuments()[0].Id;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("There's currently no content to edit. Please contact your system administrator");
        }
    }

    string redir = String.Format("{0}/canvas.aspx?redir=/{1}.aspx", GlobalSettings.Path, startNode);
    Response.Redirect(redir, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas.aspx functionality is notoriously unreliable and patchily supported so it's not a surprise if one browser reacts differently.  On my level 2 Umbraco cert course the tutor and everyone in the room agreed that it was not production ready.

I can't entirely replicate your problem, but logging into the back-office in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE9 has Chrome as the odd one out - with IE9 and Firefox reacting the same way.  Oddly for me Chrome was the only one **not** to work.

I was logging into umbraco and then in each instance firing up another tab with the url:

<.. domain ..>/canvas.aspx?redir=/pagename/

(my sites have the umbracoUseDirectoryUrls key set to true so the .aspx format is replaced by a trailing slash).

So my answer is that canvas.aspx is not reliable and therefore I would log admins into the standard /umbraco/ back office rather than trust canvas.aspx.